# Prestashop EUR currency not visible

Tags: prestashop

I have a multishop setup. I tried to set change the currency of one store from EUR->SEK and tried to deactivate EUR for one store. Somehow ended up having SEK in both stores, admin etc. EUR option is not visible at all.

I tried to reset currencies by doing this: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/92565-rezolved-i-accidentally-deleted-the-euro-curency-in-the-bo-please-help-me/

This reset the currencies (deleted SEK) but I still do not see EUR currency. When I look at the currency table in SQL, EUR is there, but somehow it is hidden in backoffice.

Any thoughts?

Many thanks in advance!